# Apache Detects files as directories

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, httpd.conf

I have a file 'result.txt' in my documentroot, now when I access:

```
http://localhost/result/first
```

It's accessing this instead:

```
http://localhost/result.txt/first
```

What could have I incorrectly misconfigured in my apache config?

**EDIT:** My rewrite rules are as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Post your rewrite rules.

Comment: @ErikA updated the post.

Comment: Does `http://localhost/result.txt/first` exist?

Comment: @John it doesn't. only `result.txt`

Comment: @Legit Can you clarify what you mean when you say "accessing this instead"? Does the URL in the browser change to have `/result.txt/`? Or is it showing up in a log somewhere?

Comment: yes the url of the browser change.

Comment: yes the url of the browser changes from `/result/first` to `/result.txt/first`.

Answer (score 0):

Where did he get ".txt"? Not from the rewrite rules as I see.

Search for "txt" string in your apache config files (entirely) and disable rewrite rules.